# Problems with using AWK with XARGS

Tags: linux, awk, xargs

I'm having trouble with the following command -->

```
find . -type f -name 'out*' |
  xargs awk 'BEGIN{print "Filename, Energy"}/TOTAL ENERGY/{print FILENAME, "," $4}' >> energy.csv
```

I want it look through all the directories for the output files, parse out the energy and then write this to the file energy.csv along with a header column.

The issue is that sometimes it writes the header column more than once in the middle of the file, but not always. I do not understand this behavior.

Comment: `xargs` will run more than once if the awk command + environment + all the filenames is too long to fit in a single invocation - hence more than one invocation of the `BEGIN` rule

Comment: If you want exactly one header, `echo *header* > energy.csv` once up front (to clear the output file), and omit the `BEGIN` block. Note the `FILENAME,` will insert an extra space before the `","`.

Answer (score 4):

`xargs` (or `find`) will call whatever command you tell them passing that command as many file names at a time as they like, always less than would cause `ARG_MAX` to be exceeded.

So your awk script is getting called with multiple batches of input files and its `BEGIN` section is being executed each time awk is called. We can avoid that problem by doing the initial printing of the header line outside of the awk script before `find` starts running.

So, do this:

```
{
    ofs=','
    printf '%s%s%s\n' 'Filename' "$ofs" 'Energy' &&
    find . -type f -name 'out*' |
        xargs awk -v OFS="$ofs" '/TOTAL ENERGY/{print FILENAME, $4}'
} > energy.csv
```

or this (`find` can call commands itself, you don't need to pipe its output to `xargs` which would be less robust):

```
{
    ofs=','
    printf '%s%s%s\n' 'Filename' "$ofs" 'Energy' &&
    find . -type f -name 'out*' -exec \
        awk -v OFS="$ofs" '/TOTAL ENERGY/{print FILENAME, $4}' {} +
} > energy.csv
```

I made the awk part a bit more idiomatic too and got rid of the spurious blank you would have had after the `,` in the header and before the `,`s in the rest of the output.

Comment: the `-v OFS="$ofs"` could also be moved to after the closing quote of the awk command, as : `| xargs awk '.....' OFS="$ofs"` . As a matter of fact: xargs will, even when splitting the awk invocation into multiple invocations, keep repeating those initial arguments along with the awk invocation. I tested that with a `foo.bash` script containing: `printf "%s " "$@" ; printf "\n"` , and then : `yes '__long_filename__' | head -n 10000 | xargs ./foo.bash bar=1 a b c | grep "bar=1" | wc -l` returned 8 instead of just 1, so it did repeat those initial arguments each time it spawned a new awk command.

Comment: @OlivierDulac awk behaves a bit more intuitively if you init variables with `-v` (will be available in BEGIN section and won't clutter up ARGV) rather than putting them in the arg list among the file names (won't be available in BEGIN and will clutter up ARGV)., Try, for example, `awk -v var=7 'BEGIN{print var, ARGV[1]}' file` vs `awk 'BEGIN{print var, ARGV[1]}' var=7 file`. The only time I'd set a variable in the args list is if I need it to change values between input files, and that's usually just when I'm setting RS or FS to different values, e.g. `awk '...' FS=, file.csv FS='\t' file.tsv`

Comment: [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) does a good job of covering the various ways to use the value of a shell variable in an awk script and the pros/cons of each. There's also the comp.unix.shell FAQ I wrote about this a lifetime ago and can't edit so take it for what it's worth - https://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.

Comment: Thank you, Ed, for these 2 comments, I didn't grok that it made them unavailable im BEGIN (I should have guessed as they are im the place where the FILENAME are... bit I didn't!). I'll go read those links :)

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` (for cross-args) is a command that reads words on input and passes them a`cross` as `arg`uments to a command.

Its input can be of indefinite length, but the number of arguments that one may pass to a command is limited, and even if it wasn't, as the list of arguments must be passed as a whole, it would not be desirable to pass them all as for a continuous flow of words on its input, `xargs` would need to read them all, store them all in memory and only when the end of input is reached (if ever) would the command then be started.

Also note that `find` doesn't produce the list of words (here file paths) in the format expected by default by `xargs`. To chain them together you'd need `find ... -print0 | xargs -r0 cmd...` or just the standard `find ... -exec cmd... {} +`.

So `xargs` will typically run `cmd` (in your case `awk`) several times if the list of files is big enough, and each `awk` will run its `BEGIN` statement.

A number of GNU commands (`wc`, `sort`, `du`...) have recently added a `--files0-from` option (or `-files0-from` predicate in GNU `find` or `--null --verbatim-files-from --files-from` in GNU `tar`) for them to take the list of files to process NUL-delimited from a file or stdin (like `xargs -r0` does) instead of as arguments, which avoids the limit, avoids storing the whole list in memory and means they can start processing files as soon as they're read from stdin.

For instance,

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -print0 | wc --files0-from - -w --total=always
```

Would print the number of `w`ords in the `.txt` files as and as soon as `find` finds them and print a `total` line in the end, which is much better than `find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec wc -w --total=always {} +` where `find` and `wc` would not run concurrently and where more than one `total` line could be output.

GNU `awk` doesn't have such an option yet, but you should be able to implement it yourself using something like:

```
find . -type f -name 'out*' -print0 | sort -Vz |
  gawk '
    function inputfile(  old_RS,ret) {
      if (ARGC > 1) delete ARGV[ARGC - 1]
      old_RS = RS
      RS = "\0"
      ret = getline ARGV[ARGC++] < "-"
      RS = old_RS
      if (ret <= 0) exit(-ret)
    }
    BEGIN  {inputfile()}
    ENDFILE{inputfile()}

    # then your awk script
    BEGIN{
      OFS = ","
      print "Filename", "Energy"
    }
    /TOTAL ENERGY/ {print FILENAME, $4}' >> energy.csv
```

(though in this particular case, it's much simpler to just print that header outside of `awk` as [Ed has shown](/a/768275)).

An equivalent with `perl -lan` would be something like:

```
find . -type f -name 'out*' -print0 | sort -Vz |
  perl -lane '
    sub nextfile {
      local $/ = "\0";
      my $file = <STDIN> or exit;
      shift @ARGV;
      push @ARGV, $file
    }
    BEGIN {nextfile}

    BEGIN {$, = ","; print "Filename", "Energy"}
    print $ARGV, $F[3] if /TOTAL ENERGY/;

    nextfile if eof'
```